# LTI Response Help

Tags: control-system, lti-system

A system is known to be LTI. The response of the system to a step function u[n] is δ[n] + δ[n-1].

a.) Find the response of the system to 2u[n] + u[n-1]

b.) Find the response to the unit impulse δ[n].

My professor hasn't been doing a good job of explaining this concept so far, please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> a.) Find the response of the system to 2u[n] + u[n-1]

If you have a linear system described by a response *H*,  then you know that

\$ H(\alpha{}x_1 + \beta{}x_2) = \alpha{}H(x_1) + \beta{}H(x_2)\$.

Since the input you're being asked about is a linear combination of unit step functions, and you know the response to a unit step function, you can work out the response from this principle.

> b.) Find the response to the unit impulse δ[n].

The Kronecker delta function used in discrete time systems has value 1 at *n*=0 and 0 for all other *n*. Therefore you can write

\$ \delta[n] = u[n] - u[n-1] \$,

and then you can use linearity again to find the system response.

Comment: Hi, so is a. simply 2δ[n]+2δ[n-1]+δ[n-1]+δ[n-2] ???

Comment: You can do one more simplification step, but that's basically it.

Comment: Combining like terms --> 2δ[n]+3δ[n-1]+δ[n-2]

Comment: You got it now.